# Search query in jsonb column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

I have a `stage` table that has a `jsonb` column named `title`.

The value of `title` is a ruby **hash** value, e.g. `{en: "A", de: "A" }`

Now I wrote the following scope for searching a `stage` based on the title in the Rails model

```
scope :search, ->(query) { where('title @> ?', { "#{I18n.locale}": "%#{query}%" }.to_json).any? }
```

but it does not work and it's giving me all items in the RSpec test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `->>` JSON operator together with `ILIKE` to do pattern matching:

```
scope :search, ->(query) {
  where("title->>'#{I18n.locale}' ILIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
}
```

Comment: but I got this error message ```ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid:
       wrong number of bind variables (1 for #<Arel::Nodes::Count:0x00005578ffa1a3b0>) in: title->>en ILIKE ?```

Comment: @kia Ah, I shouldn't have wrapped the string in Arel.sql. Edited.

Comment: now I got this error ```ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "en" does not exist
       LINE 1: SELECT "stages".* FROM "stages" WHERE (title->>en ILIKE '%A1...``` bacause I access `title` in backe-end like this -> `title[:en]`

Comment: Ah sorry. The key name needs to be quoted `title->>'en' ILIKE ?`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/58944b/5

Comment: also, we should write SQL query with `sanitize_sql` for passing from **brakeman**